# If the Laurent series for $f(z)$ converges on the boundary of an annulus, is $f(z)$ analytic on the boundary?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading about Laurent Series, I have two doubts.

**Doubt 1:** If the Laurent series for $f(z)$ converges on the boundary of an annulus,
is $f(z)$ analytic on the boundary?

I think the answer should be NO. As set of points where a complex valued function is analytic is open.

The above statement means $f$ is analytic on $r\leq|z-z_0|\leq R$ which is a closed.

**Doubt 2:**  Can $f(z) $ and $f(1/z)$ be analytic at the same set of points?

Thanks.

Comment: Answer for doubt 2): principal logarithm has this property.

Comment: For 1 the Laurent series can converge without the function being Analytic. For 2 any constant function has that property.

Comment: @N.S. Can you give some example for $1$. Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: For point 1) I think you conclusion is correct but not your reasoning.  It's not true that the set of points where the function is analytic is the same as the set of points where the series converges.  The function can certain be continued passed boundary points at which it is analytic.  You need to show that if it were analytic at every point on the boundary, then the radius of convergence would be larger.